# Given $s,n,k$ such that $n\ge k+1$ prove the following: $\sum^s_{r=0} {n+r \choose k} = {n+s+1\choose k+1} - {n\choose k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I found this question online and I can't solve it. I need to solve it without algebraic expansions.
Given $s,n,k$ such that $n\ge k+1$ prove the following:
$$\sum^s_{r=0} {n+r \choose k} = {n+s+1\choose k+1} - {n\choose k+1}$$

Comment: Have you tried induction over $s$ ?

Comment: Please write titles specific to the question.

Comment: Do you know Vandermonde's Identity?

Comment: See the idea posted by Jose Ramirez and use Vandermonde's Identity.

Answer (score 2):

I think it telescopes away by using the recurrence formula for the binomial coefficients:
$$\binom{n + r}{k} = \binom{n + r + 1}{k + 1} - \binom{n + r}{k + 1}$$